# How can I find a list item by key in a custom class with complex structure?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I have a custom python class (abstracted from real world example) which I'd like to retrieve specific records in a list by key (name). I'm trying quite a lot of new python features for the first time so bear with me if I'm doing something dumb.

```
class Person():
  def __init__(self, name)
      self.name = name

  class Hobbies():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def __getitems__(self, key):
        return next((item for item in self.items if item['hobby'] == key), None)

    def add_hobby(self, hobby):
        self.items.append(hobby)


class Hobby():
    def __init__(self, hobby):
        self.hobby = hobby

    def __get_item__(self, key):
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
        return pp.pformat(self.__dict__)



person = Person("James")
hobbies = person.Hobbies()

hobby = Hobby({'hobby1': [{'name':'walking', 'regularity':'Daily', 'type':'physical'}, {'hobby2':['name':'reading', 'regularity':'Weekly', 'type':'mental']}})

hobbies.add_hobby(hobby)
```

First, I'll apologise for the example I've chosen, it makes little sense but does convey the structure I'm working on and I've copied this code without running it as its on a machine with no python installed :(

I can't seem to see how to be able to get a specific hobby record by key.

I've tried a number of things and keep getting "None" return so my list comprehension is clearly wrong (or my understanding of the structure)

I'd like to get the dictionary object printed for any item like:

```
print(hobbies['walking'])
```

or

```
print(hobbies['hobby1'])
```

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. Please work on them first before others can help you.

Comment: `__getitems__` should be `__getitem__`

Comment: What is `item['hobby']` supposed to be? `item` is a `Hobby` instance, not a dictionary.

Comment: I don't understand the structure of the dictionary you're passing to `Hobby`. Why are the values lists?

Comment: Why are you nesting the classes? You tagged this `inner-classes`, so you seem to think this is relevant, but nothing in the code depends on it being nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the method should be [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__).

You need nested loops, so you can loop over the top-level `self.items` list and then the nested dictionaries in each `Hobby` object. In the last loop you have to compare with the `name` element.

Since the elements of `self.items` are `Hobby` instances, you need to access the `hobby` attribute with `.hobby`, not `['hobby']`.

```
class Hobbies:
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for item in self.items:
            for v1 in item.hobby.values():
                v2 = v1[0] # list always contains just one element
                if v2['name'] == key:
                    return v2
        raise KeyError(f'{key} not found in {self}')
```

`print(hobbies['walking'])` should then print:

```
{'name':'walking', 'regularity':'Daily', 'type':'physical'}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I think I can see how to proceed from here, my structure has a list in it but it's a single element. not sure what the d is in "return d" and if the "raise KeyError" is meant to be there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change that variable when I added an extra level of nesting.

Comment: Why is it a list if it's always a single element?

Comment: I'd prefer it not to have a list but that's the structure I have, I might try and manipulate it to remove as it doesn't need to be there

Comment: Just tested and with a slight amendment, this worked a treat, much appreciated.

Comment: In that case you can just use `v2 = v1[0]` instead of iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all the syntax errors, it seems like you are trying to create complex data structures with relationships among each other. In that case, inner-classes don't make much sense instead your use case could be abstracted in a much simple representation.

```
class NameMissing(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Hobby:
    def __init__(self, hobby_data):
        self.__dict__ = hobby_data
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__dict__

class Hobbies:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data={}
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Hobbies: \"{}\".".format("\", \"".join(self._data))
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[key]
    def add(self, hobby_data):
        try:
            self._data[hobby_data["name"]]= Hobby(hobby_data)
            print("Added Hobby \"{}\"!".format(hobby_data["name"]))
        except KeyError:
            raise NameMissing("`name` is missing from hobby data.")

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hobbies = Hobbies()
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name} with {len(self.hobbies._data)} Hobbies."
```

If my understanding is correct you are trying to create a relationship between a person and their hobbies, in this case just initialize the hobbies object inside the person's init method and the dict-like structure of hobbies object should take care of the rest. I added **repr** methods to describe the classes better.

Output-

```
>>> person = Person("Christopher Nolan")
>>> person
Christopher Nolan with 0 Hobbies.
```

Check the Hobbies -

```
>>> person.hobbies
Hobbies: "".
```

Now add some

```
>>> person.hobbies.add({'name':'walking', 'regularity':'Daily', 'type':'physical'})
Added Hobby "walking"
>>> person.hobbies.add({'name':'reading', 'regularity':'Weekly', 'type':'mental'})
Added Hobby "reading"!
>>> person.hobbies.add({'name':'awesoming', 'regularity':'Hourly', 'type':'cosmic'})
Added Hobby "awesoming"!
```

Hobbies look different now

```
>>> person.hobbies
Hobbies: "walking", "reading", "awesoming".
```

To get the individual hobby -

```
>>> person.hobbies["reading"]
{'name': 'reading', 'regularity': 'Weekly', 'type': 'mental'}
>>> person.hobbies["reading"].name
'reading'
>>> person.hobbies["reading"].type
'mental'
>>> person.hobbies["reading"].regularity
'Weekly'
```

Comment: Thanks abhinavn, that helps a lot, I think I've created some unnecessary complexity and will rework this simplify.